# jsp session valid or not showing html content

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I am trying to create session on this jsp page with my servlet. Session is working properly but the problem is that whether the session is valid or not the page is showing the html content. I want to show my html content only if session is valid.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ include file="header.jsp"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <%@ include file="menu.jsp" %>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="content.css">
    <title>Home</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <%
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    if(session.getAttribute("username")==null){
    out.println("please login");
    }
    else{
     out.println("Welcome User");
    }
    %>

    <table>
    <tr>
    <td><p id="matterfirst">
    VMS is developed and customized for commercial fleet owners and organizations. Its modules support most type of vehicles (Passenger, Truck, Construction and other Commercial Vehicles). It really reduces your vehicles cost while increasing performance and dependability. Track your tax-deductible business miles and travel expenses. Eliminate costly unscheduled maintenance. Increase the resale value of all your vehicles. Keep accurate records for any type of vehicle. Help you plan annual vehicle budgets faster, easier and more   accurately Keep track of Party Ledgers
    Payment Receipt). Keep track of Driver and other employee ledger.
    </p>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="galleryborder">
    <img id = "pic1" alt="car" src="images/pic1.jpeg">
    <img id = "pic2" alt="bus" src="images/pic2.jpeg">
    <img id = "pic3" alt="truck" src="images/pic3.jpg">

    </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Well, the HTML code is *after* the if/else block, instead of being *inside* the else block, so that's quite expected, isn't it? Also, please avoid scriptlet in JSPs. Learn the JSP EL and the JSTL.

Comment: @JB Nizet - I already tried this option, putting html code inside else block but its not working out.

Comment: It should. Post what you tried, and describe *how* it doesn't work.

Comment: @JB Nizet - I apologize, my mistake. I was ending the script outside the body and I forgot that I am adding two files which was not written inside the else block. Thanks alot.